# Building and installing HHVM on CentOS error on last part

Tags: centos

i follow this https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/Building-and-installing-HHVM-on-CentOS-6.3 and I'm almost done but in the last part wich is

`cd hiphop-php`

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
export HPHP_HOME=`pwd`
export HPHP_LIB=`pwd`/bin
cmake .
make
```

the eror says

[root@localhost hiphop-php]# cmake .
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH was missing, proceeding anyway
CMake Error at CMake/FindBoost.cmake:916 (message):
Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.
Boost version: 1.41.0
Boost include path: /usr/include
Detected version of Boost is too old.  Requested version was 1.48 (or
newer).

despite those errors i did follow this

If your failure was on the @make@ command, try to correct the error and run @make@ again, it should restart from the point it stops. If don't, try to remove as explained above.
If you met some issues on build, You could also try to upgrade your Boost to 1.50 version and GCC to 4.6.1 version: You could follow this instruction for build BOOST: https://github.com/jackywei/HOW-TO-BUILD-HHVM-WiKi/wiki/Build-&-install-Boost-1.50-in-CentOS-(CentOS5.2-&-6.3-are-both-verified)

but still same error

please help thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check what version of boost is installed (through RPM):

```
rpm -qa boost
```

It will probably be boost-1.41. Erase that package (rpm -e) and then install Boost 1.50.